# Arduino Text Scrolling on 16x02 I2c on NodeMcu (ESP8266-12)

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, lcd, communication

I have managed to get my 1602 I2C LCD working on a NodeMCU devkit. I can display text parsed from the web but I am not sure how to set it to autroscroll if message is greater than 16 characters. I tried the `lcd.ScrollDisplayLeft()` but it doesn't work. I figured I would have to do it manually and it is a matter of getting string length and then looping the characters.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>  // This library is already built in to the Arduino IDE
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> //This library you can add via Include Library > Manage Library >  

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 16, 2);

const char* ssid = "ssid"; 
const char* password = "pass";
const char* host = "api.thingspeak.com";

int find_text(String needle, String haystack, int from) {
  int foundpos = -1;
  if (haystack.length() < needle.length())
    return foundpos;
  for (int i = from; (i < haystack.length() - needle.length()); i++) {
    if (haystack.substring(i, needle.length() + i) == needle) {
      foundpos = i;
      return foundpos;
    }
  }
  return foundpos;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);
  lcd.init();   // initializing the LCD
  lcd.backlight(); // Enable or Turn On the backlight
  delay(200);

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  lcd.print("Connecting");
  lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    lcd.print(".");    
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Connected!!");
  delay(1000);
}
int value = 0;

void loop() {

  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 80;
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");

  }

  // We now create a URI for the request
  String url = "/apps/thinghttp/send_request?api_key=345345345345345";
  Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(url);
  // This will send the request to the server
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);               
  lcd.print("Fetching Data..");
  delay(10000);

  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  while (client.available()) {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');

    int start_loc = find_text("<b>", line, 0);
    int end_loc = find_text("</b>", line, 0);    
    if (start_loc > 0 && end_loc > 0)
    {
      lcd.clear();
      Serial.println("data:  ");
      lcd.print("data: ");
      lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
      for (int i = start_loc + 3; i < end_loc; i++)
      {
        Serial.print(line[i]);
        lcd.print(line[i]);
     }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("closing connection");
  delay(2000);

}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Inspecting the library code](https://github.com/fdebrabander/Arduino-LiquidCrystal-I2C-library/blob/master/LiquidCrystal_I2C.cpphttp://), it is apparent that the method called only sets up a command bit field and it is actually the display that performs the operation.

So, you might check if your LCD is capable of performing the scrolling operation.

[This web page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LiquidCrystalScroll) contains a tutorial on how to use the scrolling feature.  In this code example from that page:

```
void loop() {
  // scroll 13 positions (string length) to the left
  // to move it offscreen left:
  for (int positionCounter = 0; positionCounter < 13; positionCounter++) {
    // scroll one position left:
    lcd.scrollDisplayLeft();
    // wait a bit:
    delay(150);
  }
```

...you can see that it is not automatic.  That you need to call the method each time you want to scroll (in this case) one position to the left.